# como alterar a data usando o datatables

Tags: jquery-datatables

tenho uma datatables que tem um campo data.

Pretendo alterar esse mesmo campo de 2012-05-01 00:00:00.000 para 2012-05-01.

É possivel?

Answer (score 1):

```
->editColumn('created_at', function ($user) {
            return $user->created_at->format('d/m/Y');
    })
```

Se você estiver usando o laravel você pode acrescentar o editColumn que ele ja sai do controller formatado.

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível.

Você deve usar a função **render** do plugin datatables.

http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#function

Exemplo:

```
{
    "data": "minha_data",
    "render": function (data) {
        var date = new Date(data);
        var dataFormatada = date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
        return dataFormatada;
    }
}
```

Isso na declaração da suas columns.

Aconselho a usar um plugin para formatação de data como por exemplo https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Editado

Mais informações sobre Date em javascript http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: ola era quase isso mas no dia e no mes fico apenas com um numero

Comment: ola @user2964140 por isso eu aconselhei o uso de um plugin de formatação de data. Pois caso você não queria usar um vai ter que criar sua lógica para formatar a data de acordo com suas necessidades. De qualquer modo veja o link que coloquei na edição da minha resposta